# Displaying samples based on ONLY the first 1000 rows in azure databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

```
dfResult = spark.readStream.format("delta").load(PATH)
dfResult.createOrReplaceTempView("Stream")
```

Trying to read streaming data from the delta table where I had put all data into and visualize them by doing :

```
%sql
SELECT Time, score
From Stream
```

However, only the first 1000 rows are shown on the graph or table.

Are there any ways to see the last 1000 rows or display the whole data instead of the first 1,000?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ID to sort the dataframe and subset it using limit() to ensure you get exactly the rows you want.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# add an index column (if you don't have it)
dfResult = dfResult.withColumn('index', f.monotonically_increasing_id())

# sort ascending and take first 1000 rows for df1
df1 = dfResult.orderBy("index", ascending=True).limit(1000)

# sort descending and take last 1000 rows for df2
df2 = dfResult.orderBy("index", ascending=False).limit(1000)

display(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks but, such an error shows: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expression(s): monotonically_increasing_id() is not supported with streaming DataFrames/Datasets;;`

Answer (score 0):

try ordering by date instead

```
display(dfResult.orderBy("Time", ascending=False).limit(1000))
```

Comment: `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;;`  It says that sorting is not supported on streaming dataset

Comment: @BrianLee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259015/why-does-streaming-dataset-fail-with-complete-output-mode-not-supported-when-th